# Functioning of append in dictionary?

Tags: python

Please explain the use of `append` function in the following example:

Example 1:

```
new = {}
for (key, value) in data:
    if key in new:
        new[key].append( value )
    else:
        new[key] = [value]
```

and in example 2:

```
new = {}
for (key, value) in data:
    group = new.setdefault(key, []) 
    group.append( value )
```

Comment: The `append` function is not part of the dictionary. It's a method on the list that is stored as a value in the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

`new` is a dictionary, but the dictionary’s value are lists, which have the [`list.append()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) method.

In the loop, the dictionary is being filled with the values from `data`. Apparently, it is possible that there are multiple values for a single `key`. So in order to save that within a dictionary, the dictionary needs to be able to store multiple values for a key; so a list is being used which then holds all the values.

The two examples show two different ways of making sure that the dictionary value is a list when the key is new.

The first example explicitly checks if the key is already in the dictionary using `key in new`. If that’s the case, you can just append to the already existing list. Otherwise, you need to add a new list to the dictionary.

The second example uses [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) which sets a value *if* the key does not exist yet. So this is a special way of making sure that there’s always a list you can append the value to.